# Changing database encoding with existing data

Tags: mysql, encoding, character-encoding

If I change the encoding of my database, tables and related columns from `latin1_swedish_ci` (default) to `utf8_general_ci` to show European and other characters, will that apply to any existing data, or only to new inserts?

I currently have names showing up as `RubÃ©n` which don't fix themselves even when changing that column's encoding to `utf8_general_ci`.

**Do I have to re-import my data into the database, or can I apply encoding changes to existing data 'in-place'?**

Comment: How should the DB know that those characters are actually malformed in human's eyes? All it knows is that it's been told to store exactly those characters. So, yes, you'll basically need to convert them yourself.

Comment: This might help: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/12/18/fixing-column-encoding-mess-in-mysql/

Comment: Ok. I thought the data stored internally might be fine, but decoded improperly.

Comment: @Andre Please put that as an answer and I'll accept it. My issues are fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
UPDATE table SET column=CONVERT(CONVERT(column USING binary) USING utf8) WHERE id=123;
```

Source:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/12/18/fixing-column-encoding-mess-in-mysql/